# Check if user is already logged in or or not in MFP V8.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have written an adapter procedure in MFP V8.0. This procedure is secured bu a security check. I want to check that user is already logged-in before calling this adapter procedure:

Procedure is mapped to scope as below:

```
<procedure name="searchData" scope="restrictedResource"/>
```

Security Check is defined as below:

```
<securityCheckDefinition name="UserValidationSecurityCheck" class="com.sample.UserValidationSecurityCheck">
```

I have done the the Scope Element mapping the server also.

I have written below method which calls the adapter method:

```
function callAdapterProcedure(invocationData){
    var procedureName = invocationData.procedure;
    var successHandler = invocationData.successHandler;
    var failureHandler = invocationData.failureHandler;
    var parameters = invocationData.parameters;

    var isuserLoggedIn = checkForLoggedInUser();
    alert('is logged in' + isuserLoggedIn);
    if(isuserLoggedIn){
        var dataRequest = new WLResourceRequest(getAdapterPath(procedureName), WLResourceRequest.GET);
        dataRequest.setQueryParameter("params", [JSON.stringify(parameters)]);
        dataRequest.send().then(successHandler,failureHandler);
    }else{
        hideProgressBar();
        showAlert(Messages.ALERT_SESSION_TIME_OUT);
        logoutWithoutConfirmation();
        openLogin();
    }
}
```

Below is the implementation of `checkForLoggedInUser()` method:

```
function checkForLoggedInUser(){
    var userAlreadyLoggedIn = undefined;//WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated(mrmGlobal.realms.authenticationRealm,null);
    WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken("restrictedResource").then(
        function (accessToken) {
            alert("obtainAccessToken onSuccess");
            userAlreadyLoggedIn = true;
        },
        function (response) {
            alert("obtainAccessToken onFailure: " + JSON.stringify(response));
            userAlreadyLoggedIn = false;
    });

    return userAlreadyLoggedIn;
}
```

I know that `WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken` sends the asynchronous call to the server that's why `userAlreadyLoggedIn` is always coming as `undefined`. Is there any way through which I can check that the user session is not timed out before making the adapter call? Basically I want to implement something like `WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated` (which was there in earlier versions).

**--Update--**

Plus I have observed one more thing that the handlers method of `WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken` are also not getting called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your code:

```
 WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken("restrictedResource").then(
        function (accessToken) {
            alert("obtainAccessToken onSuccess");
            userAlreadyLoggedIn = true;
        },
        function (response) {
            alert("obtainAccessToken onFailure: " + JSON.stringify(response));
            userAlreadyLoggedIn = false;
    });
```

It is a common misconception to think that `obtainAccessToken's onFailure` means the user is not logged in. But that's not exactly how it works.

When you call `obtainAccessToken`, there are 3 possible outcomes:

- Success: The user is logged in, and `obtainAccessToken onSuccess` is called (along with the challenge handler's success method).
- **Challenge**: The user is not logged in, the security check sent a challenge to the client. **This challenge will be received by your challenge handler. `obtain` will remain on hold until you answer the challenge.** This is probably what happens in your case, this would not explain why none of the obtain's handlers are being called.
- Failure: Something went wrong during the authentication. It could be that the server is down, networking issue, the scope does not exist, or the user is blocked, etc. In this case, `obtainAccessToken's onFailure` will be called.

There currently is no API to check if a scope is granted without triggering a challenge. I have opened an internal feature request, feel free to submit your own (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe  ).

In the meantime you could add your own internal boolean flag, that you set to true whenever you login and false whenever you logout.

Comment: It was really very informative Nathan. Is there any other way I can check if user is already logged in or not similar to WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated?

Comment: But what if my session is expired? How can I handle it?

Comment: You'll get a challenge when trying to access the protected resource. The whole framework is built around the concept of challenges triggered by protected resources.

Comment: Yes..that I know...what what will happen is as soon as that challenge is answered the procedure protected by security check will get fired and I don't want that to happen. Is there any way I through which I can stop that to happen?

Comment: Not through any built in apis that's for sure. Keep in mind that even if you had such an API, it could never be 100% safe. There is always a chance the security check chooses to reject the request.

Comment: By the way even the old isUserAuthenticated API did not take expiration into consideration. It basically behaved the same way as a custom Boolean flag.

Comment: Thank you Nathan for all the responses. I will accept this as an answer to m question.